# Python multi-project build

Tags: python, build, dependencies

I'm in the process of splitting up a monolithic project code base into several smaller projects. I'm having a hard time understanding how to handle dependencies amongst the different projects properly.

The structure looks somewhat like this:

```
SCM_ROOT
|-- core
|   |-- src
|   `-- setup.py
|-- project1
|   |-- src
|   `-- setup.py
|-- project2
|   |-- src
|   `-- setup.py
`-- project3
    |-- src
    `-- setup.py
```

What's the recommended way to handle dependencies between multi-package projects and setup a development environment? I'm using pip, virtualenv and requirements.txt files. Are there any tools that allow me bootstrap my environment from the repository quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a build tool like Pybuilder or Pants was unnecessarily complicating the process. I ended up splitting it up into multiple projects in svn - each with it's own trunk/tags/branches directories. Dependencies are handled using a combination of install_requires and requirements.txt file based on information from [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-package-dependency-blues) and [here](http://cramer.io/2012/04/24/sticking-with-standards/). Each project has a fabfile to run common tasks like clean, build, upload to pypi etc.